# Good model design strategies

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, model-view-controller

I am working my way through iOS programming these days and am not sure if my program implementation strategies are the greatest way to go about doing things.

From my understanding, the model should be a run alone program, that is if I were to call it's functions through the command line by providing the requisite inputs, the program ought to execute itself and yield the desired results.

Several times, I find my model and VC interwined together. That is, although the VC is purely handling the View and user input and accordingly calling the functions established in the model, it still seems to me that the model would not function independently without the presence of a view.

My question is essentially framed from this quirk, do you guys insist on your models' to run independently from the View controller or is it OK to have them intervined and dependent one each other.

Comment: I don't know how you came to your understanding of the model, but it's not quite correct. Your model should be self contained so you could wrap it up in a command line program, if you wished. Or run tests against it. But it doesn't need to be a separate executable.

Answer (score 1):

The model should not communicate directly with the view at all.  The model should communicate with the view controller only in response to a query made by the view controller.  The view controller should mediate between input entered into the view and the data inside the model.  It's definitely important to keep all these parts separated. Your app will still work even if you don't and in some cases it may be quicker to take shortcuts, but you will only set yourself up for a lot of pain in the future when you deal with all the issues down the road.  There are great videos on iTunes Connect about this.  Especially video #1 in CS193P which covers MVC, see:

- [Developing Apps for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/cs193p-student-final-projects/id395605774) (Fall 2010)
- [iPad and iPhone Application Development](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255) (Fall 2011)

Answer (score 1):

Your model shouldn't contain any controller or view code. You should be able to test it without any need for controllers or views.

Your controller should be handling all the work of mediating between the model and the view.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem as I've struggled with the same. But you're using too vague of language to allow a good answer to come through.

For example, you say "I find my model and VC interwined[sic] together". What exactly do you mean by "intertwined"? The View Controller knows of the interface to the model and interacts with it. That's normal, right?

The short/vague answer is that your View Controller shouldn't be doing any "model" stuff (handling data and calculations) and your Model shouldn't be doing any view or controller stuff (worrying about button presses, loading PNGs, etc).

When you say "it still seems to me that the model would not function independently without the presence of a view", that's also too vague for me to concretely address it, but even well designed models just "sit there". They need something stimulating them and interacting with them. That might be test code in one case, or a View Controller in another. That doesn't mean you're doing anything wrong.

If you look in the right column of your question here on SO, you'll see at least 10 similar questions regarding MVC, so go do some reading :)